# Convert from UTF-8 to Shift-JIS

Tags: php

The current email is in UTF-8. It's not working on Shift-JIS. 
How can I convert from UTF-8 to SHIFT-JIS. The solution needs to be a PHP solution.

This is what I have tried so far

```
$subject = mb_convert_encoding ($subject, "JIS", "SJIS");

$subject = base64_encode ($subject);

$subject = "=?iso-2022-jp?B?" . $subject . "?=";
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can convert utf-8 to shift-JIS by doing this:

```
$str = mb_convert_encoding($str, "SJIS", "UTF-8");
```